# Http post in android with nested associative array

Tags: java, android, http-post, multidimensional-array, basicnamevaluepair

I am trying to send an http post request to a PHP service. Here is an example of how the input may look with some test data
[image]

I know that the Java alternative to the PHP associative arrays are HashMaps, but I wonder can this be done with NameValuePairs? What is the best way to format this input and call the PHP service via post request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can be done with `NameValuePair`.You can have something like

```
List<NameValuePair> params;
//and when making `HttpPost` you can do 
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("Yoururl");
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

//and while building parameters you can do somethin like this 
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "firemanavan"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cvr", "1245678"));
....
```

Here's a neat and nice parsing method which you can use.

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String json = "";
    JSONObject jObj = null;

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }


    return jObj;

}
```

And you can simply use it something like

```
getJSONFromUrl("YourUrl", params);
```

Now this is just a basic idea of how you can achieve this using `NameValuePair`.You will have to need some more workaround to implement exactly as you want, but this should provide you the basic idea.Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Together with @Illegeal answer it works perfectly. I just had to modify the User's data, since it is an array in an array. This is how I did it for the user's data: 
`params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User[0][name]", "name"));`

Comment: Great. Glad it worked for you. Please accept an answer for all your questions in SO if it worked for you.

Comment: Yeah sure. I do accept this answer even though I also got some good inspiration from @Illegeal answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Extending @Sash_KP's answer, you can post the nameValuePairs like this too:

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Company[name]", "My company"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User[name]", "My Name"));
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had to modify the User's data, since the associative array 'User' contains another associative array named '0'. This is how I did it: 
`params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User[0][name]", "user's name"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User[0][surname]", "user's surname"));`